# Add logo to ggplot2 in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, r-grid

I'm trying to utilize the method [outlined here](https://michaeltoth.me/you-need-to-start-branding-your-graphs-heres-how-with-ggplot.html) to add a logo to a plot, but in a loop. It works fine for one plot, but in a loop it doesn't print as expected. Note that the first R logo is placed prior to anything else, and then is dropped from the last plot.

[image]

I'm utilizing it in quarto to put out as a html document, though I don't think that should matter with the code.

````
---
title: "Logo Plot Question"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
editor: source
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r}
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(magick)

# # Create data
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,
  value=c(25,49,36,18,45)
  )

logo <- magick::image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/1448px-R_logo.svg.png")

for (i in 1:2){

  print("Start plot")
  
p <- ggplot(data, aes(name, value)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1,  aes(fill = value)) +
     coord_polar(clip = "off") +
     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 50)) +
     theme_void() +
     theme(legend.position = "none") +
     labs(title = paste0("Plot ", i))


grid::grid.raster(logo, x = 0.5, y = 0.5, 
                  just = c('center', 'top'),
                  width = unit(0.5, 'inches'))
print(p)

# Does not work...
# p2 <- grid::grid.raster(logo, x = 0.5, y = 0.5, 
#                   just = c('center', 'top'),
#                   width = unit(0.5, 'inches'))
# 
# print(p2)

print("End plot")

}
```
````

Note: I've seen solutions that suggest using ggsave() to save as an image and then reimport in. I would like to shy away from this as I am creating a report and don't want hundreds of images sitting around.

Comment: {cowplot} might be helpful: https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html#combining-plots-and-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to keep ggplot objects *as* ggplot objects. The linked article *draws over* an existing `ggplot`.

I would probably use a custom annotation in most cases, but this doesn't work with polar co-ordinates, so I would instead make a logo-only ggplot that I could add to any plot using the `inset_element` function from the `patchwork` package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(magick)
library(patchwork)

data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,
  value=c(25,49,36,18,45)
)

logo_plot <- ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob( x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
    image_read(paste0("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/",
                      "commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/",
                      "1448px-R_logo.svg.png")), 
    just = c('center', 'center'), width = unit(0.5, 'inches')))

for(i in 1:2) {
  
  cat("Here's plot", i, "\n")
  
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(name, value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1,  aes(fill = value)) +
    coord_polar(clip = "off") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 50)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste0("Plot ", i)) +
    inset_element(logo_plot, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  
  print(p)
}
```

Now the Quarto output is:

[image]

Comment: I agree that I would rather have it as a ggplot object. As I'm playing around with it I realize one of the reasons others may have drawn over an existing plot is that their solutions allows you to place the logo outside the plot area. For instance, if one wants a title on the left via `labs()`,  and the logo to the right, you would need to draw the logo outside the plot area.

Comment: @seansteele you can also put the logo outside the plot area by using `align_to = "full"` in `inset_element`

Answer (score 0):

My version of the code uses the `lapply` function to generate and print the plots, which eliminates the need for a for loop. The base plot is defined separately, and then customized within the `lapply` function for each plot. This makes the code more concise and easier to read.

```
# Load libraries
library(grid)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Define data
data <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  value = c(25, 49, 36, 18, 45)
)

# Define logo plot
logo_plot <- ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
                               image_read(paste0("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/",
                                                 "commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/",
                                                 "1448px-R_logo.svg.png")), 
                               just = c('center', 'center'), width = unit(0.5, 'inches')))

# Define base plot
base_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(name, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1,  aes(fill = value)) +
  coord_polar(clip = "off") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 50)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Generate plots
plots <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  base_plot +
    labs(title = paste0("Plot ", i)) +
    inset_element(logo_plot, 0, 0, 1, 1)
})

# Print plots
lapply(plots, print)
```